# AJAX display only a part of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax call to display a php page, it works well as follow:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr = false;
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   else {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhr.open("GET","http://foo.com/bar.php",true); 
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        document.getElementById('ajax_response').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
 </script>
```

However, I would like to display only a div of the page, I tried to use xhr.responseXML but it returned a null value, and JQuery $.load or $.ajax don't work. Is there a way to handle the xhr.responseText to get only one part of the whole page? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> $.load or $.ajax don't work

It should work.

```
$("#ajax_response").load("/bar.php #container");
```

`#container` is the part you want to load.